# Java Regex for start with fixed digits 53 or 54 or 55 then a seven digit number

Tags: java, regex

I need a regular expression to validate USA SIT id,

In the US sit id start with 53 | 54 | 55 so, can i know the regex to evaluate code start with 53 | 54 | 55 followed by 7 digit number.

I do now know how to build a regex!

Comment: you can use this regex [`^5[3-5]\d{7}$`](https://regex101.com/r/52uRZS/1)

Answer (score 1):

Like mention in comment you can use  `5[3-5]\d{7}`, below, an example of matchinf input with the regex

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("5[3-5]\\d{7}");
Matcher m = p.matcher("541234567");
boolean b = m.matches();
```

in this case `b is true` if the input matches with the regex and `false` if not

Comment: You can just use `boolean check = "541234567".matches("5[3-5]\\d{7}");` not need to Pattern and Matcher :)

Comment: `[3-5]` == `[345]`

Comment: Can i get regex for proper Business name?

Comment: What did you mean @GuruprasadAN ?